# Creation Failed: Key column 'name' doesn't exist in table:

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, notnull

I am trying to create a series of tables using Foreign Keys of Primary Keys from other tables, however I always get the error

`Table Creation Failed: Key column 'PACId' doesn't exist in table:`

Here is the first case it appears:

```
CREATE TABLE PlantAreaCodes(
  PACId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AreaCode INT,
  AreaName CHAR(32),
  Comments TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (PACId)
);

CREATE TABLE MajorEquipment(
  MEId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (MEId),
  FOREIGN KEY (PACId) 
  REFERENCES PlantAreaCodes(PACId)
);
```

Is it to do with the syntax of the foreign key, or is it because the PACId is still empty, and cannot be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that `PACId` is *empty*.  You haven't declared it in `MajorEquipment`.

Try using this definition for the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE MajorEquipment(
  MEId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PACId INT, -- Added this column
  PRIMARY KEY (MEId),
  FOREIGN KEY (PACId) 
  REFERENCES PlantAreaCodes(PACId)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a55b81) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks I did not realise that. Too focussed on the issue to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE MajorEquipment(
  MEId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (MEId),
  PACId INT 
  REFERENCES PlantAreaCodes(PACId)
)
```

Comment: FWIW, MySQL does not support column-level constraint syntax.

Comment: MySQL reports no error, but does not create the constraint. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE MajorEquipment` and you'll see.